# html email send with php=correct in outlook(win), but is plain text on Mac Mail

Tags: php, html, windows, macos, email

I'm sending an email with php in html format. 
When receiving it in Windows = layout is correct and attachments are there. 
when receiving it on Mac = it shows the code below (I've removed some from the html email but you get the idea). Hopefully some of you can help me out on this one.

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--==Multipart_Boundary_x58e7a5e9f21d360b63401b3fab7a3a88x
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
                <head>                  
                </head>

                <body>

                    <div align="center">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="headertitle"><img src="http://mysite.eu/sources/img/header.jpg" width="550" height="100" alt=""></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550">
                                        <tr>                                        
                                            <td width="510" align="left" valign="top">
                                                <font face="Arial" size="3" color="#000000">
                                                <p>test email</p>
                                                </font>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="20"></td>
                                        </tr>   
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                    <div align="center"><img src="http://www.mysite.eu/sources/img/line2.jpg" width="518" height="21" alt=""><br>
                                     <font face="Arial" size="1" color="#231F20"> contact details here
| Email <a href="mailto:contact@mysite.eu" style="text-decoration: none;"><font face="Arial" size="1" color="#231F20">contact@mysite.eu</font></a> | <a href="http://www.mysite.eu" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><font face="Arial" size="1" color="#231F20">www.mysite.eu</font></a>
                                  </font>
                                  </div>
                                  </td>
                                   </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </body>
                </html>

--==Multipart_Boundary_x58e7a5e9f21d360b63401b3fab7a3a88x

--==Multipart_Boundary_x58e7a5e9f21d360b63401b3fab7a3a88x--
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've re-formatted the code in your question so it shows up properly.

Answer (score 0):

We used theese for Mac Mail:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; charset="UTF-8"; boundary="b1_28ffe645f1d2d11a286709f14eeb1e0f"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

--b1_28ffe645f1d2d11a286709f14eeb1e0f
Content-Type: text/plain; format=flowed; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

if it not works: http://linktocontent

--b1_28ffe645f1d2d11a286709f14eeb1e0f
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<html>...</html>
--b1_28ffe645f1d2d11a286709f14eeb1e0f--
```